# Trouble with editing items in list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I wanted to a make a list of list using pythons and I know two methods to do it.

The first method is like so:

```
l = []
l_in = []
for j in range(2):
   l_in.append("1")
print l_in
for i in range(2):
   l.append(l_in)
print l
```

and the second method is:

```
l = []
for i in range(2):
   l.append([1]*2)
print l
```

Both these methods creates a list

```
l = [['1', '1'], ['1', '1']]
```

I want to change only on element `int` this list say the `(1,1)` element. If I do

```
l[1][1] = "Something I want to replace with"
```

the element should be replaced. This works fine for the second method. But if I use the first method both `(1,1)` and `(0,1)` changes to `"Something I want to replace with"`.

Can someone tell me why using the first method gives this output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because in the first method, in the second loop you are appending the same list twice.

```
for i in range(2):
    l.append(l_in)
```

Now whenever you're modifying an element in `l`, you are actually modifying elements in *one* list. An easy way to understand is to look at the values the builtin `id()` gives for the content of `l`.

```
>>> map(id, l)
[32750120, 32750120]
```

You can see that both elements in `l` share the same id (and the same memory address). They both refer to the same list `l_in`.

As Aशwini चhaudhary suggested, an easy fix is `l.append(l_in[:])` where the `[:]` creates a copy of the list `l_in`.

```
l = []
l_in = []
for j in range(2):
   l_in.append("1")
print l_in
for i in range(2):
   l.append(l_in[:])
print l
```

You can also create lists of lists with list and generator comprehensions. Some examples below:

```
# empty lists..
>>> [[] for _ in range(4)]
[[], [], [], []]

# generator expression..
>>> list([] for _ in range(4))
[[], [], [], []]

# [1, 1] for each sublist.
>>> list([1, 1] for _ in range(4))
[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
```

Here's the `help()` on `id()`:

```
Help on built-in function id in module __builtin__:

id(...)
    id(object) -> integer

    Return the identity of an object.  This is guaranteed to be unique among
    simultaneously existing objects.  (Hint: it's the object's memory address.)
```

Comment: And a quick fix is to use `l.append(l_in[:])`

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary Added that, thanks. SO has some encoding problems :)

Comment: That is intentional, I don't want people to use keyboard to type my name. :P Anyways I already gave you a +1.